# Splitting (stacking) labels in ArcMap in multiple lines using vbScript?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, vbscript

I want to show labels in ArcMap on multiple lines. The label I have is written as: `Caritas Lebanon Migrant Center, DRC, Handicap International, NRC, SCI`. 
I want to show it in separate lines. e.g.:

```
Caritas Lebanon Migrant Center, DRC, 
Handicap International, NRC, SCI
```

Or:

```
Caritas Lebanon Migrant Center, DRC, 
Handicap International, NRC, 
SCI
```

Is that possible to do using an expression?

Answer (score 2):

You could probably write a vb expression to replace every second comma, but I find it easier to work in python. Something like this would work:

```
def FindLabel([LABELFIELD]):
    labels = map(str.strip, [LABELFIELD].split(','))
    out = ''
    for i in xrange(0, len(labels), 2):
        if i + 1 < len(labels):
            out += '{}, {}\n'.format(labels[i], labels[i + 1]))
        else:
            out += labels[i]
    return out
```

Comment: Output comes like this: P,r,i,v,a,t,e, ,P,m, ...........

Comment: @Mehmud oops, sorry. Forgot to split the label field. I've edited the code.

Answer (score 1):

The ArcGIS Desktop help on [Building label expressions](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-text/about-building-label-expressions.htm) explains how to use vbScript to:

> Create stacked text. For example, this expression creates a label with
>   the Name field and the two address fields all on separate lines:

```
"Name: " & [NAME] & vbCrLf& [ADDRESS_1] & vbCrLf& [ADDRESS_2]
```

Comment: This line of code worked for replacing comma(,) with new lines. 
`FindLabel = replace([LABELFIELD], ", ", vbnewline)`
But I was looking for to replace every 2nd comma. Thanks for the help.as always.

Comment: That sounds like a slightly harder question so I think you should edit it to explain that the label is coming from only one field, and more precisely your scenario.